# Is it safe to install different OS to a Windows Vista laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista

I am going to install 64bit Windows 7 on my laptop that had 32bit Windows Vista on it. I checked and it seems like the processor `Intel Pentium T3400` is actually 64bit, so everything should be OK.

Is there any possibility that it will not work? Could the laptop be somehow locked to Windows Vista only, via hardware etc?

How about installing (older OS) Windows XP ? Could some of the laptop's hardware features  stop from working?

What should I take into account when installing the OS? Does laptops need some special versions of the OS's to be installed? Or does "one size fit all" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's "Safe" is pretty hard to answer, and we'd need to know way more information about your notebook to answer with full confidence.

But, in general:

- Check the specifications of your notebook.
- Check the requirements for the version of Windows you wish to use.
- Check with the notebook's manufacturer to see if they provide drivers for that version and bit-level of Windows.
- Make a backup before trying.

IME, if it runs Vista 32-bit there's a good chance it will run Windows 7 32-bit just fine.

You can also utilize Microsoft's [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows/downloads/upgrade-advisor).

Comment: Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor did the job.

Answer (score 2):

PCs are never locked to a specific OS (AFAIK). So, you should not be blocked to install a different OS.

Now, a PC - specifically a laptop - contains many devices, and all must be supported by the OS you're installing (Windows 7 64-bit). You should look at the laptop manufacturer's site, and see whether it offers drivers for your specific laptop. Also check whichever external devices you plan on using - printers, etc.
That said, a Vista-era laptop will probably be supported without much problems.

You should probably flash the PC's BIOS before installing, just for good measure.

Comment: Why do i have to flash the PC's BIOS? what the flashing actually means?

Comment: @Rookie: If you don't need any of the new features or bugfixes from a BIOS update, you probably should not risk flashing. If unsuccesful, it may render the motherboard useless.

Comment: @MarcksThomas, thats what i thought.